# How do I get the commands for PyPDF2 in Python

Tags: python, pypdf

If I enter from the command line...

> python -m pip
>   I get a list of the pip commands.

If however I enter

```
python -m pypdf2
```

I get "...no modules named pypdf2...".

From the shell, if I enter

```
>>>help("pypdf2")
```

I get "No documentation found for pypdf2".

If I get a list of the modules with help("modules"), pypdf2 is the first module listed, not in alphabetical order like the rest of the modules.

I can download the documentation on line, but I am curious does this just mean that there is no documentation for pypdf2 in python?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install it? Assuming you've done `python -m pip install pypdf2`, you should note that the actual package name is **`PyPDF2`**. So even though the install works lower/mixed case, you have to use the actual name to import it or access its help docs: `PyPDF2` vs `pypdf2`:

```
>>> import pypdf2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypdf2'
>>> import PyPDF2
>>> help(PyPDF2)
Help on package PyPDF2:

...
>>> help("pypdf2")
No Python documentation found for 'pypdf2'.
Use help() to get the interactive help utility.
Use help(str) for help on the str class.

>>> help("PyPDF2")
Help on package PyPDF2:

...
```

PS. I didn't know that `help()` also accepts the *object's name as strings* rather than the object itself. Was going to point that out as an error, but tried it myself and saw that it works. Thanks!

PS2. So that allows providing the object name (as a string) to read the help docs without needing to import it first. Nice.

````
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> # no import here
>>> help(PyPDF2)    # won't work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'PyPDF2' is not defined
>>> help("PyPDF2")  # works, still not imported
Help on package PyPDF2:
```
````

Comment: Btw, if you don't require backwards compatibility with Python code written for PyPDF2, consider using [PyPDF4](https://github.com/claird/PyPDF4) instead.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to use PyPDF2 as the community is way bigger / a lot more features are in there

Answer (score 0):

The name you need to import is `PyPDF2`. Not `pypdf2`, not `pyPdf2` or anything else.

Capitalization does matter for the import. It doesn't for the install.

However, PyPDF2 does not have any command line utility, so this is expected:

```
$ python -m PyPDF2
/home/martin/.pyenv/versions/3.8.9/bin/python: No module named PyPDF2.__main__; 'PyPDF2' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```